# Can a left join be expressed as a right join and vice versa?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, outer-join

Suppose we have an `EMPLOYEE` and a `DEPENDENT` table. Each employee has an identifier Ssn and possibly a dependent with identifier Essn. Are the following two queries equivalent?

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.Lname, D.Dependent_name
FROM ((EMPLOYEE E) LEFT OUTER JOIN (DEPENDENT D) ON E.Fname=D.Dependent_name);

SELECT DISTINCT E.Lname, D.Dependent_name
FROM ((DEPENDENT D) RIGHT OUTER JOIN (EMPLOYEE E) ON E.Fname=D.Dependent_name);
```

In general, is it true that

```
(TABLE A) LEFT OUTER JOIN (TABLE B)
```

is the same as

```
(TABLE B) RIGHT OUTER JOIN (TABLE A)
```

?

Comment: If you invert the tables you can use left join   eg. tableA  right join tableB is the same that tableB left join tableA

Comment: Yes,  that's how it is supposed to work.  I've noticed that it is more common to use the first form (LEFT JOIN) ,  but I assume because it is more natural to start writing first the data you need and after that the optional ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true, however, I strongly recommend not to use RIGHT JOIN.
Since our natural reading order is from left to right and top to bottom, RIGHT JOIN comes very unnatural in this manner.
Also, If you'll have a mix of LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN it would be very, very hard to follow through.

Comment: Hi @David דודו Markovitz I liked your answer and voted for it, therefore, don't you recommend mixing LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN either? Of course, in your experience

Comment: Right join vs Left join is just a matter of writing order. Inner join and left join have different logic and are not exchangeable. I would usually prefer to put all inner joins at the beginning and the left join afterwards, but there are exceptions

Comment: Great, thanks a lot @David דודו Markovitz I really needed your opinion based on experience.